# I invite you a little game where I want to make the ellipsis to be link

Tags: html, css

The first solution is working. As you see:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ellipsis.whole.html</title>
  <style>
    a {
      text-decoration : none
    }
   .box {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 250px;
  }
   .box p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 
<body>




 <h1>Solution 1</h1>

 <div class="box">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Aenean vehicula odio ac nisl
dignissim hendrerit. Proin libero arcu, commodo
in aliquam porta, dignissim sodales<span><a href="http://www.google.com/">...</a></span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here comes the second solution! I can not see difference between two but the second does not work. Could anybody know what is the difference between two? I have seen it multiple but no answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ellipsis.link.html</title>
  <style>
   a {
    text-decoration: none;
   }
   
   .box {
      background-color: #ddd;
      width: 250px;
   }
   
   
    .box p {
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
  <h1>Solution 2 </h1>

<div class="box">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Aenean vehicula odio ac nisl
dignissim hendrerit. Proin libero arcu, commodo
in aliquam porta, dignissim sodales tortor. Sed
dignissim mi cursus quam sollicitudin, vitae
semper nunc finibus. In id turpis velit. Nullam
finibus lobortis lacus vel egestas. In pretium
dictum ligula quis pulvinar. Aenean id dolor metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec commodo elementum erat blandit blandit.
Cras quis elementum mi<span><a href="http://www.google.com/">...</a></span>.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why could I not click on the ellipsis at the second version of code? I am waiting for your answers curiously!

Comment: You have a bigger text in second example. Change '...' with 'abc' in the first example and you'll see that is '...' are manually generated. However, second example you have bigger text and you limited it with 5 lines and '...' has been generated dynamically.

Comment: because the ellipse in the second solution is not your `<a>...</a>` and thus not clickable. The ellipse in the second solution is created from the overflow of text and the `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;`. Remove it and you will see it disappear.

Comment: because of the text truncate with line-clamp attribute.

Comment: In Mozilla, I don't really see much difference. Both links are clickable (although Google doesn't like being opened in a frame), so maybe you should just get rid of the webkit-only stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you will see, you will notice that in both versions you have limited the amount of lines to 5 in this part of code:

```
-webkit-line-clamp: 5;
```

Thus in the second example (where there is a lot more of text) the '...' part is not clickable, because the elippse creates three dots to show that there is a text that continues. If you try and change that number to "15" (as to 15 lines) the whole text will show and the last '...' part will be clickable. You can also remove the

```
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

part and the code will ignore the upper line limit and show the whole text, no matter what you put in the 'line-clamp' tag in the code.